# How do I force Windows 7 to reevaluate or recognize my monitor resolution after hibernate or sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, resolution, external-display

I have a Lenovo W500 Laptop with an ATI FireGL 5700 card and it has VGA and a [Display Port](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).

Everything works fine if I boot my laptop with a monitor already attached. Sometimes it also works if I attach a monitor afterwards. But there are problems after hibernate or sleep mode.

If I use a monitor via VGA, then activate hibernate or sleep mode, unplug VGA and attach a different monitor via Display Port the resolution is correct but the Hz is wrong and I cannot select the right one as there is no such option. I have a strange monitor that uses 59 Hz instead of 60 (at least that is what Windows tells me). If I select 60 Hz the screen gets smaller and I get the effect of watching widescreen movies on a 4:3 monitor (black border). But even if I try to change the resolution there is no option for 59 Hz.

I have no problem if I need to readjust my resolution, but how can I force Windows to recognize the *correct* or *optimal* monitor settings so I can select them? I do not want to reboot my laptop every time.

I am not sure if the problem is the hibernate or sleep mode, as the two monitors are not in the same location, one is at home the other one in my office.

Answer (score 1):

In the Screen Resolution control panel, click the **Detect** button. That should force Windows to redetect the monitors and their supported resolutions and refresh rates.

[image]

Comment: Tried this, but still does not work.